# PHP shorthand logical operators AND and OR

Tags: php, logical-operators

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP - and / or keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502092/php-and-or-keywords)
>   [PHP shorthand syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475047/php-shorthand-syntax)

Quick question. I keep seeing shorthand expressions in libraries around the place, and despite having been a PHP developer for over 3 years, I struggle to quite see how the following would evaluate.

What exactly does the PHP interpreter do with the following shorthand lines of code when it encounters them?

```
<?php
    defined('foo') OR exit('foo is not defined!');

    $foo AND $this->bar();
```

I'm guessing that it' obviously conditional execution - i.e. the second statement won't get executed unless the first bit is true... but the use of the bitwise operators confuse me a bit.

Can someone elaborate?

Thanks :)

Comment: @Gordon - no not really. I know that && is the same is AND, likewise with || and OR. I was enquiring about the shorthand logic - which has now been pointed out to me as short circuit evaluation.

Comment: well, how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475047/php-shorthand-syntax then?

Comment: someone just linked me to that. what exactly is your issue?

Comment: I'm just pointing out possible duplicates. On a sidenote, the guy who answered with that link shouldnt have answered with that link. It should have been a comment or a closevote. That's why I copied it up here and flagged his answer for not being an answer. It's all just housekeeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back when I was learning PHP I remember reading the 'do or die' style commands and not fully understanding them at the time, the classic example is:

```
mysql_connect() or die('couldn\'t connect');
```

Bear in mind that the conditions will only run if they're required, for example:

```
if (a == b && b == c)
```

Here b == c will only be tested if a == b.  The same theory applies to or:

```
if (a == b || b == c)
```

Now b == c will only be tested if a != b.

In this case you are relying on this order to run a command (exit or $this->bar()) in certain conditions.

**Be Aware...** exit() is a bad idea in this circumstance - if you exit('something went wrong') there's nothing anyone can do to hide this error from the user, also it's likely to issue a 200 OK HTTP status where a 500 Internal Server Error would be much more appropriate, I would consider something more like:

```
defined('foo') OR throw new Exception('foo is not defined!');
```

Here you have a chance to either catch the Exception or at least let PHP catch it and issue a 500 status.

Mat

Comment: Hey Mat, thanks for the answer. Yeah I know it's not the best way at all. I actually just pulled the example from most files in the core of CodeIgniter... which is a heavily PHP 4 oriented framework.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this is a form of short-circuit evaluation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Essentially, when evaluating an entire expression, the interpreter short circuits once it is certain of the result. For example:

```
true OR do_something();
```

This expression never calls do_something() because the first operand of OR is true, so the entire expression must be true.

Answer (score 2):

Much less elaborate than you think. The `or` keyword is the same as `||`, except it has lower precedence. See the [corresponding PHP page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for details.

The actual execution of this statement relies on a separate concept involving logical operators: short circuiting. This means that, in the case of `or`, the second statement is not evaluated if the first statement turns out to be true. (Since in a conditional, for instance, the entire condition would return true without ever needing to see the second half.)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have a function that looks something like:

```
function test()
{
    $foo = TRUE;
    $bar = FALSE;

    return $foo && $bar;
}
```

In this case, if some does:

```
 $bla = test();
 if($bla) {
   ... do something
 }
```

The "...do something" will not get executed, because the function as a whole returned false.

return $foo && $bar means that both variables have to be true in order for the function to return true.

On the other hand, if it stated: return $foo || $bar; then the function would return true, because at least one variable is true.